# Resteasy Client Wildfly 23 - IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: json, wildfly

I use Wildfly 23.
I tried to implement a Resteasy Client (Version 4.7.0).
Here is my code:

```
    ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilderImpl().build();
    ResteasyWebTarget getEvent = client.target("https:......");
    Response getEventResponse = getEvent.request().get(); ...
```

But I get this error when "ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilderImpl().build();" is invoked:

```
 Failed to define class org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ResteasyClientImpl in Module "deployment.isymnd.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Failed to link org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/internal/ResteasyClientImpl (Module "deployment.isymnd.war" from Service Module Loader): Implementing class
```

Does anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong?
Thank you a lot,
Nicole

Comment: Why not use the standard JEE methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a newer version of the client than WildFly 23 provides. WildFly 23 uses 3.15.1.Final. You should also ensure you're not including the JAR in your deployment.

Comment: I could not find any information about which versions wildfly provides. Do you have a link for me (compatibility matrix or something like that?) Thanks.

Comment: I guess there really isn't a component matrix.You would use the WildFly BOM though https://github.com/wildfly/boms. WildFly 25 does move to 4.7.0.Final though.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to use the JEE API for jaxrs client (especially as you are using Wildfly !)

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

client.target(baseUri)
     .path("/users")
     .path(userId)
     .path("/roles")
     .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
     .post(...);
```

More info:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/package-summary.html

Comment: I will check the javaee 7 methods. Thanks.